# DOM when not an actual document

Tags: javascript

Ok, lets say I go to http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif , which is not really a document, but an image, iin my browser.  Does it still have a document object?  Can I use `javascript:` in my location bar?  Wha'ts the deal with this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look with Firebug reveals that yes indeed, there is a DOM and a document object. For example, `javascript:alert(document.title)` in the location bar gives "logo.gif (GIF Image, 276x110 pixels)". This results from the construction of the following document by the browser:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>logo.gif (GIF Image, 276x110 pixels)</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" alt="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is also true in Chrome (with a slightly different string for the title); the HTML is

```
<html>
    <body style="margin: 0px;">
        <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif">
    </body>
</html>
```

In IE, it appears that `document.title` is empty, but `javascript:alert(document.body.clientWidth)` gives a result equal to the client area of the browser, so it looks like there's a DOM there as well. The HTML is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" complete="complete"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is extremely implementation-dependent. Internally, some browsers will build a fake HTML page that will display the picture, but you can't rely on that.

Comment: If by "some" you mean "all"... (OK, I haven't tested Presto, but we have Gecko, WebKit, and Trident represented here; it's a pretty safe bet.)

Comment: You're right that you shouldn't rely on it, however; this is easily the kind of stuff that could be changed in a later version.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser. If you go to that URL in firefox, for example, and open the DOM Inspector, you will see an `html`, `body` and `img` tag; also, typing `javascript:alert(document)` in the location bar will alert `[object ImageDocument]`. IE8 exhibits similar behaviour (but alerts just `[object]`).

Answer (score 0):

no... the browser simply acts as a picture viewer

Comment: duh... What does that have to do do with there being a DOM?